# Understanding fourier coefficients

Tags: fourier-series, orthonormal

In my text book it says that if $c_n$ are fourier coefficients of $f$ and $f_n$ is an orthonormal set then

$\bigg( \sum_{n=1}^N c_n f_n, f - \sum_{n=1}^N c_n f_n\bigg) = 0$

This is not immediately obvious to me and I am wondering if someone has a proof of this?

Comment: The equation doesn't make sense.

Comment: $(c_n f_n(x), f(x))$ is the inner product of $c_n f_n$ and $f$

Comment: the left sum is a number, the right one is a function

Comment: You have made a mistake in transcription. I would guess that you are trying to show that $(\sum_n c_n f_n -f) \bot  f_k$.

Comment: yes sorry  I am struggling with this you were all right. I have fixed it I believe.

Comment: it is still wrong. check again

Comment: ok i think i finally copied it right.... my apologies

Answer (score 2):

We have:

$$\left( \sum_{n=1}^N c_n f_n, f - \sum_{n=1}^N c_n f_n\right) = \left(\sum_{n=1}^N c_nf_n, f\right) - \left(\sum_{n=1}^N c_n f_n , \sum_{m=1}^N c_m f_m\right) \\ = \sum_{n=1}^N c_n (f_n,f) - \sum_{n=1}^N\sum_{m=1}^Nc_n c_m \underbrace{(f_n,f_m)}_{= \delta_{nm}} \\ = \sum_{n=1}^N c_n^2 - \sum_{n=1}^Nc_n^2 = 0$$

Answer (score 1):

This is a slightly stronger result from which the other follows. It says that the error in approximating $f$ by $\sum_n c_n f_n$ is perpendicular to the linear subspace spanned by the $f_n$.

If $c_n = \langle f, f_n \rangle$, and $k \le n$, then
$\langle f-\sum_n c_n f_n , f_k \rangle = \langle f, f_k \rangle - \langle \sum_n c_n f_n , f_k \rangle = c_k - c_k = 0$